# CSS backgrounds

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm learning CSS at the moment and I am using it on a website to control the layout of the site.

I Have a number of containers, 5 of them, all on top of each other, I have a background for the page but I also want to use a background for one of the containers. So I used the `'background-image:url("");'` tag to use a background, the I also used the attachment, repeat. The problem I was the image wasn't setting itself to the container, it was pushing out way past the dimensions that I had set in my CSS code which were `height:312px;` and `width: 1000px`;

Here is the CSS

```
html, body 
{
margin-top: 25px;
padding: 0;
background-image:url("../../images/background.png");
background-repeat: none;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }

.hidden 
{
display: none;
}

#page-container 
{
width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
background: transparent;
}

#header 
{
height: 130px;
}

#content-top
{
background: #D9D9D9;
background-image:url("../images/pic.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:right top;
height: 312px;
width: 1000px;
 }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="page-container">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="flashContent">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content-top"><!--<img src="images/pic.png">--></div>

    <div id="portfolio-container">

        <div id="portfolio1"><p>1</p></div>

        <div id="portfolio2">2</div>

        <div id="portfolio3">3</div>

        <div id="portfolio1"><p>4/p></div>

        <div id="portfolio2">5</div>

        <div id="portfolio3">5</div>

    </div>

    <div id="main-content">
        main-content
    </div>

    <div id="footer">Footer</div>

</div>
```

I haven't pasted all of the CSS but its needed let me know.

Its as if the background is filling a space that is a lot bigger than the space specified.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the background image?

Comment: They are 312 by 949 I wanted it to sit on the right hand side of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I needed to do something like this, I did the following:

```
#background{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; max-width:1024; max-height:768; height:auto; z-index:-1; }
```

And then on my page I included the following:

```
<img id="background" src="whatever.jpg" alt="" title="" />
```

And that was it. This actually works quite nicely, with the background image magically resizing itself until one of the dimensions (width or height) reaches the maximum specified.

It doesn't need `CSS3` support. Try it and see.

Obviously tweak the positioning stuff if you don't want it to fill the screen (I did).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set `background-size` to 100%

It only works in browsers supporting CSS3

Comment: That has solved the problem, but has kind of created a new one. Now the image is stretched to fit the container width, i wanted it to sit on the right hand side of the container... If i make a smaller box in side this container and set it to 100% that should work and i'll also be able to get a nice boarder around it. Is this a good approach to solving the problem?

Comment: You could also place an <img> tag inside and set it's and the overlapping element to `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

Try float:left in #contentTop

Hope that helps!

In css you also have background-size:contain/cover